# How do I select each 3rd instance after I split in powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

I stored the data in a variable from azure command $bandwidth = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail.

Now when I call `$bandwidth.InstanceID` I have 888 objects of some thing like:

`/subscriptions/0858ffa5-d2dd-420f-a958-85f6911c121fe/resourceGroups/AZR-AEX-SCCUSTMETRICSPROD-Development/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/ wmstoragemboxlandingdev /subscriptions/0858ffa5-d2dd-420f-a958-85f6911c121fe/resourceGroups/AZR-AEX-SCCUSTMETRICSPROD-Development/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/ wmstoragemboxlandingdev`

I'm trying to extract the Resource group name from each line in which I tried the below approach:

`bandwidth.InstanceID -split ('/')`

Now I how do I select only the resource group name for each object in a single line of code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below :

```
$bandwidth.InstanceID | %{$_.split('/')[4]}
```

**Explanation :**

- **$bandwidth.InstanceID** - This is your output array of InstanceID.
- **%** - Foreach operator
- **$_** - iterative element passed from the previous pipe - here $bandwidth.InstanceID
- **split('/')** - this method returns the array of all split string
- **[4]** - this is the array index of the split string in which resource group name resides.